# How to convert an ISO timestamp field in JSON to epoch using jq

Tags: json, timestamp, jq

I have an array of JSON messages like this:

```
{
  "type": "Point",
  "time": "2021-04-01T01:19:21.243866342Z",
  "value": 1,
  "metric": "iterations",
  "method": "",
  "name": "",
  "proto": "",
  "status": "",
  "tls_version": "",
  "url": "",
  "expected_response": "",
  "group": "",
  "scenario": "default",
  "agent_hostname": "ip-13-3-3-33.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal",
  "agent_ipaddress": "33.3.3.3",
  "agent_casetype": "simplerequest",
  "agent_casename": "test_case"
}
```

This is a message that is generated by an app and stored in a folder. I would like to convert the time fields from the ISO to epoch-microseconds.

I could use this: .time_field | .[0:-9] | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") | mktime

But this remove the entire decimal part and gives me only second granularity. This is trending data and a few events may happen within the same second.

How can I achieve that using jq?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do? Did you read `jq` documentation?  Did a whole section about `Dates` in there maybe catch your eye?

Comment: `https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions`  search for "Dates". There are functions to convert to *seconds* since epoch.  Documentation does not mention *microseconds* since the epoch.

Comment: Too bad this got closed: I have a killer jq answer. I'd encourage you to: read the jq docs; make an attempt at solving it; and edit the question with your efforts.

Comment: I edited the question now. Is there a way to do this with jq? I only included awk and sed in my original question because I suspected jq may not be able to deliver the microseconds granularity.

Comment: @glennjackman - over to you.

Comment: Right, no pressure now. Performance anxiety...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the time functions only working with integral seconds. This answer uses a string function to parse out the fraction.

If this is `file.json` contains an array of objects

```json
[
    {
        "type": "Point",
        "time": "2021-04-01T01:19:21.243866342Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "Circle",
        "time": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.01Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "Line",
        "time": "1970-01-01T01:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

Then

```sh
jq '
    def datestamp2epoch:
        . | scan("(.+?)([.][0-9]+)?Z$")
          | [(.[0] + "Z" | fromdateiso8601), (.[1] // 0 | tonumber)]
          | add;
    map(.time |= datestamp2epoch)
' file.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "type": "Point",
    "time": 1617243561.2438664
  },
  {
    "type": "Circle",
    "time": 1577836800.01
  },
  {
    "type": "Line",
    "time": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: Tip: `[(.[0] + "Z" | fromdateiso8601), (.[1] // 0 | tonumber)] | add` simplifies to `(.[0] + "Z" | fromdateiso8601) + (.[1] // 0 | tonumber)`

Comment: sweet!! It does exactly what I need.

Comment: Hello Glenn. Is there a version of this script that addresses the following format: "2021-04-20 10:03:46.000000"

Comment: I don't know. What does the jq manual say about it?