Format JSON Date Value with Quotes for Bash Script
Hi I have a bash script which i am reading from a JSON using jq and writing to another JSON object.
The dates from he feed are formatted in ISO8601 like "2024-05-16T08:00:00-05:00", bash doesnt like.
I can convert the dates from epoch time to friendly format. An example line from my script reading the raw JSON epoch time: 1715864400 from the feed and format to friendly with this one liner.
dt=$(date -d @$(cat "${DrawC}" | jq '.[].EpochTime | .'))

But it is not quoted, I need to have it double quoted to read the string in my new file otherwise
I get an Invalid numeric literal error.
I've tried formatting, using quotes in all kinds of ways around the variable.
Cant seem to get it, searched but most of the results seem to think I'm asking
how to use quotes in a bash script.
Thanks

Can't you use JQ to format it to your liking?

Check your script with shellcheck.

Please show how you're using $dt in the rest of the script.

Adding quotes won't make something a valid numeric literal. A numeric literal should just contain digits, without any quotes around it.

If I knew the syntax for jq to add quotes, that be helpful. kzi suggestion looked promising but gives an unexpected EOF.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908468/how-to-convert-an-iso-timestamp-field-in-json-to-epoch-using-jq for how to convert an ISO time to epoch time in jq.

What command is producing the error message?

dt is just a variable. I have many lines different variables. All return results just fine. It is only the dates that messing with the script. I use like echo $dt >> file.

Please post a [mre] and the complete error message.

it is when i try to read the variable from the file in the json object it is witten like this: "Day1": Thu May 16 10:31:57 AM CDT 2024. If I add quotes around the value I can read it just fine to add to a function.

jq requires double quotes around the value. Why it doesn't have a date object/function baffles me.

jq is just only accepting valid JSON as it's a JSON processing tool.

try this  printf "%s\n" { "{" .. file then  dt=$(date -d @$(cat "${DrawC}" | jq '1715864400')) |  echo >> file then echo } then

what's the content of ${DrawC}? I assume, it's the name of a file, because cat is used for printing out the content of files.

DrawC is just JSON object / array file. All the contents are sound and properly formatted except the dates with quotes

Try this printf "%s\n" "{date: " >> file then dt=$(date -d @$(cat "${DrawC}" | jq '17158644file00')) | echo >> file then echo "}" >>  then dt=$(date -d @$(cat "${file}" | jq '.[].date | .' echo "$dt"

kzi that gives an unexpected EOF error

kzi that last variation returned a very strange result. It returned the entire parent json not DrawC but it's parent.

My bad. |= inside a jq statement converts a field, but doesn't chose it for printing out only this field. Try this: dt=$(cat $DrawC | jq ".[].EpochTime | strflocaltime(\"%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M\")"). Adjust the format of the timestring to your needs.

As already mentioned above in comments - run your code through http://shellcheck.net and if you still have a problem after correcting the issues it tells you about then ask a question that includes a [mcve]. See [tag:bash] and [ask].

The answer is simple. Frustrating that I already know this, and utilize it all the time, just put '"' around the variable like this.
'"'dt=$(date -d @$(cat "${DrawC}" | jq '.[].EpochTime | .'))'"'


Whatever it is you're trying to do, that is definitely not the answer, it's corrupting that line of code and trying to execute a non-existent command named "dt=... (i.e. with the " as part of the command name). If you get a better result from doing that then that means you definitely have some other problem elsewhere in your script and adding those "s isn't fixing that, it's just hiding it (probably temporarily). Copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and it'll probably tell you about some issues.
